# Slds-scrollable not working on IOS devices with Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

HTML template

```
 <div class="DataCollection">
     //content..................................
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.DataCollection{
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

how can i do this?

Comment: I don't see Scrollable being used here. Is this your correct code? But be informed that [Scrollable](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/) does not work on Mobile devices but only supports Desktop.

Comment: i have used overflow:auto so it is working as scroll

Comment: So that’s not really using slds scrollable then.

Comment: yeah if use slds scrollable that is also not working on salesfore 1 app for ios

Comment: Unfortunately horizontal scrolls don't work on iOS, I got to figure this out very recently, so you are facing the same issue here. Refer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282727/how-to-implement-horizontal-scroll-on-html-table-in-salesforce-mobile-app) where I had exactly the same issue.