# Aura component does not allow scroll in iOS only on Salesforce 1 mobile app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, css, uiscrollerwrapper

The aura component shows a list of text messages. Vertical scrolling does not work in iOS on the Salesforce 1 app. Works fine in Android. I looked at a few other questions like [Scroll issue in Salesforce1 | Lightning ui:scrollerWrapper issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173467/scroll-issue-in-salesforce1-lightning-uiscrollerwrapper-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the solutions are not working for me.

The issue is that it scrolls the salesforce 1 mobile app and not the component ui:scrollerWrapper. The component is embedded in another aura component. However in android it is able to scroll the ui:scrollerWrapper.

Comment: Vertical Scroll should work fine. We had been in [a situation where Horizontal Scroll was not working on iOS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282727/how-to-implement-horizontal-scroll-on-html-table-in-salesforce-mobile-app), but overall we found that Vertical Scrolls worked fine in iOS.

Comment: Vertical scroll is moving the tabs on the salesforce 1 app up and down, not the text messaging component.

Comment: You might want to improve this question and better encourage people to help by:
- explaining how / where this component is exposed in the Salesforce mobile app
- share image / screen recording explaining the problem further
- building the smallest reproducible example of the problem
- sharing code which isn't dependent on other metadata in your Salesforce org.